# XmlPullParser issues in Android

Tags: android, xmlpullparser, xmlexception

So on review of the code there is no exception thrown when the xml is read in...works fine.

```
public void ReadXML() throws XmlPullParserException, IOException
   {

      factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
      factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
      xpp = factory.newPullParser();

      InputStream raw = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("trial_info.xml");
      xpp.setInput(raw,null);
   }
}
```

The problem is in the doXML method where i'm trying to read the text b/w two tags...
eg.

```
<trial>
<title>The Book</title>
<author></author>
....
</trial>
```

The error that is generated is  18:19:41.654: W/System.err(329): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: name expected (position:START_TAG @59:57 in java.io.InputStreamReader@44f049c8)

I think the code is probably more complicated than it needs to be...but can't figure out the error. Thanks

```
public void doXML() throws  XmlPullParserException, IOException{


          int eventType = XmlPullParser.START_TAG;

          while(eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
          {
              if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT && xpp.getText().equals(selectedTrial))
              {
                   trialTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TrialAbbrevData);
                   trialTxt.setText(xpp.getText());
                   Log.d("what is this", xpp.getText());

           while(!(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xpp.getName().equals("...")))
                   {  

           if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && xpp.getName().equals("trialName"))
                      {    
                         eventType = xpp.next();
                         if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT)
                         {
                            trialTxtDesc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TrialNameData);
                            trialTxtDesc.setText(xpp.getText());
                            Log.d("in loop",xpp.getText());
                         }
                      }

         if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && xpp.getName().equals("trialDetails"))
                      {   
                         eventType = xpp.next();
                         if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT)
                         {
                            trialTxtConc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TrialDescData);
                            trialTxtConc.setText(xpp.getText());
                         }
                      }

         if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && xpp.getName().equals("trialResults"))
                      {   
                         eventType = xpp.next();
                         if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT)
                         {
                            trialTxtConc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TrialResultsData);
                            trialTxtConc.setText(xpp.getText());
                         }
                      }

        if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && xpp.getName().equals("trialConclusion"))
                      {   
                         eventType = xpp.next();
                         if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT)
                         {
                            trialTxtConc=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TrialConclusionData);
                            trialTxtConc.setText(xpp.getText());
                         }
                      }

        if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && xpp.getName().equals("whatItMeans"))
                      {  
                          eventType = xpp.next();
                          if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT)
                          {
                             trialTxtMeans = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TrialWIMData);
                             trialTxtMeans.setText(xpp.getText());
                          }
                      }

                      eventType = xpp.next();

                   }         



            }
              eventType = xpp.next();
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you post line 37-42 of your XML file?

Comment: I think this can happen if you mistype or don't use the same letter case in your tags. Have you tried on a short test xml file first?

Answer (score 0):

The error message seems to indicate an error in the XML file, not the code.